# Validate Automapper Source Property inside Complex Object

Tags: automapper

I need to have error that Inner.Value2 not mapped

```
using AutoMapper;

namespace AutomapperTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
                c.CreateMap<Source, Target>()
                .ValidateMemberList(MemberList.Destination)
                .ValidateMemberList(MemberList.Source));

            // I need to have error that Inner.Value2 not mapped
            mapperConfiguration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }
    }

    class Source
    {
        public Inner Inner { get; set; }
    }

    class Inner
    {
        public string Value1 { get; set; }
        public string Value2 { get; set; }
    }

    class Target
    {
        public string InnerValue1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu so we can make flattering automatically, but can't validate it automatically?

Comment: Yes, because the default flattening works without a map for the inner class and you need a map to validate. That's why `IncludeMembers` exists, for more control.

Comment: So I have to use IncludeMembers, create Map from Inner to Target and explicitly specify properties, because name conventions no longer match

Comment: You're supposed to rename stuff and move away from the default flattening. Or give up the validation you wanted. You cannot have your cake and eat it too :) No map, no validation.